# Get bulletted list in lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

So I have a html like this:

```
...
<ul class="myclass">
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah2</li>
</ul>
...
```

I want to get the texts "blah" and "blah2" from the ul with the class name "myclass"

So I tried to use innerhtml(), but for some reason it doesn't work with lxml.

I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
doc.xpath('.//ul[@class = "myclass"]/li/text()')
# out: ["blah","blah2"]
```

*edit:*

*`what if there was a <a> in the <li>? for example, how would I get "link" and text" from <li><a href="link">text</a></li>?`*

```
link = doc.xpath('.//ul[@class = "myclass"]/li/a/@href')
txt= doc.xpath('.//ul[@class = "myclass"]/li/a/text()')
```

*If you want you can combine those, and if we take @larsmans example, you can use `'//'` to get the whole text, because I belive that lxml does't support the `string()` method in an expression.*

```
doc.xpath('.//ul[@class="myclass"]/li[a]//text() | .//ul[@class="myclass"]/li/a/@href')
# out: ['I contain a ', 'http://example.com', 'link', '.']
```

Also, you can use the `text_content()` method:

```
html=\
"""
<html>
<ul class="myclass">
    <li>I contain a <a href="http://example.com">link</a>.</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah2</li>
</ul>
</html>
"""
import lxml.html as lh
doc=lh.fromstring(html)
for elem in doc.xpath('.//ul[@class="myclass"]/li'):
    print elem.text_content()
```

*prints:*

```
#I contain a link.
#blah
#blah2
```

Comment: what if there was a <a> in the <li>? for example, how would I get "link" and text" from `<li><a href="link">text</a></li>`